# org-mode built-in table editor on windows

Tags: windows, emacs, org-mode

I am using org-mode version 8.2.2 and Emacs 24.2.1 on Windows 7 and have been struggling with the alignment of org-mode tables. Creating a simple table in org-mode using the build in editor gives me an unaligned table

- unaligned table columns

| first col | second col  | third col        |

| some text   | some other text | some numbers 333 |

| extra text row | extra text      |                  |

|     |     |       |

from my experience with ubuntu I should get aligned columns when I hit tab, as:

```css
* unaligned table columns
| first col      | second col      | third col        |
| some text      | some other text | some numbers 333 |
| extra text row | extra text      |                  |
|                |                 |                  |
```

The unaligment is persistent in agenda view.

Anyone experienced the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Is your Ubantu installation of Emacs the same version, and is your org-mode installation on Ubantu the same version?  If not, how about trying it with the same thing on each OS to see if the results are the same or different?

Comment: Could you update your question to indent the "unaligned table columns" by four spaces (select and Ctrl+K)? It's hard to see how this is displaying on Windows.

Comment: @lawlist, I have tried 3 different versions of org-mode on Windows with the same result. On my Ubuntu I have tried the same version and an additional version. Both produce the correct result.

Comment: @Chris, I tried your proposal without success. Do you know if I can test the alignment of columns in Emacs outside of org-mode?

Comment: I found out, that if I paste the "unaligned table columns" into notepad++ the columns align in a correct way automatically. I now consider this problem to be an issue related to my Emacs-Windows configuration and not an org-mode issue. But, I still would like to have the option to try column alignment in Emacs, but outside of org-mode, anyone?

Comment: @ras, perhaps you're using a proportional (non-monospaced) font? Adding a screenshot might help.

Comment: @Chris, Thank you Chris, This was the problem. I have had this problem for years. I use the same .emacs for both system, but for some reason that I cant remember I changed the font. Can you post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I paste the "unaligned table columns" into notepad++ the columns align in a correct way automatically

It sounds like you're using a proportional (non-monospaced) font in Emacs.

`org-mode`'s table alignment is accomplished by adding spaces to cells as necessary, and assumes that all characters have an equal width. If you configure Emacs to use a monospaced font like [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas), [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_%28typeface%29), or [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro), your tables should align properly.